# Giving starting value to the Query in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, gridview

Can I give the query a starting value that my records should start from certain values up till end. Like I have a TextBox in which user enters the Starting value and the Limit of the loop. I am generating the values by incrementing them with in the loop and inserting them into the database as well.

Now I want to show those values into a GridView but the condition is that how can I tell my Query that it should start from the value entered in the textBox up till the values generated with in the loop.

My code looks like this:

```
int SerialNumberStart = Convert.ToInt32(Regex.Replace(StartSerialBox.Text, "[^0-9]+", string.Empty));
int SerialLimit = Convert.ToInt32(LimitBox.Text);

for (int i = 0; i < SerialLimit;i++ )
{
    SerialNumberStart++;
    SerialNumberList.Add("S" + SerialNumberStart);
}

for (int j = 0; j < SerialNumberList.Count;j++ )
{
    Adapter.insertserialnumbers(SerialNumberList[j], DateTime.Now.ToString());
}
```

And my query will be like this

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_Serialization_HeaderData]
    @SomeValue
AS
    Select *
    From Units
    Where StartingValue > @SomeValue
```

Comment: Is it winform or WPF?

Comment: Correct me if i'm not wrong. Means you want data fetch between values. Why not you use and in where clause ?

Comment: I have tried to use that but actually my starting value is not constant so first I have to tell where it has to start from then I have to add the condition using AND  in where clause.

Comment: Can you show use exactly what are you doing ?

Comment: I have shared the code with the post as well. Actually the whole scenario is that I am incrementing an integer value based on the limit what user has entered as well as the starting value like if user has entered S110910 and give the limit 5 then I am generating the numbers from S110911 to S110915. After generating them I am saving those value to the database. Now I want to show these values into the DataGridView, for that I want to tell my query that it should start from S110910 and end up to S110915.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Let assume you starting value is S110911 and end value is S110915. Your query must bi like that use 'Between' keyword.

```
string startingValue = "S110911";
string endingValue = "S110915";
string query = "Select * From Units Where UnitSerialNumber Between startingValue And endingValue";
```

This will retrun all the rows between S110911 and S110915.

Comment: No its not working as StartingValue[ColumnName] is not a keyword it gives the error that Incorrect syntax near this ColumnName

Comment: StartingValue[columnName] is just a hint.Replace StartingValue[ColumnName] with your actual columnName.

Comment: I know I have replaced it with my Column Name but it is not recognizing the StartingValue[] Like Select * 
From Units 
Where StartingValue[Units.UnitSerialNumber] 
Between START And ENDVALUE

Comment: Please tell me your column name in the database where you store S110911 value.

Comment: Its UnitSerialNumber and the table is Units

Comment: What If I do not give the Endvalue then what will be the solution?

Comment: It is necessary to give end value if you want rows in between. If your problem is solved then consider marking this as an answer.